# Multithread foreach slows down main thread

Tags: c#, multithreading, performance

Edit: As per the discussion in the comments, I was overestimating how much many threads would help, and have gone back to `Parallell.ForEach` with a reasonable `MaxDegreeOfParallelism`, and just have to wait it out.

I have a 2D array data structure, and perform work on slices of the data. There will only ever be around 1000 threads required to work on all the data simultaneously. Basically there are around 1000 "days" worth of data for all ~7000 data points, and I would like to process the data for each day in a new thread in parallel.

My issue is that doing work in the child threads **dramatically** slows the time in which the main thread starts them. If I have no work being done in the child threads, the main thread starts them all basically instantly. In my example below, with just a bit of work, it takes ~65ms to start all the threads. In my real use case, the worker threads will take around 5-10 seconds to compute all what they need, but I would like them all to start instantly otherwise, I am basically running the work in sequence. I do not understand why their work is slowing down the main thread from starting them.

How the data is setup shouldn't matter (I hope). The way it's setupmight look weird I was just simulating exactly how I receive the data. What's important is that if you comment out the `foreach` loop in the `DoThreadWork` method, the time it takes to start the threads is waaay lower.

I have the `for (var i = 0; i < 4; i++)` loop just to run the simulation multiple times to see 4 sets of timing results to make sure that it wasn't just slow the first time.

Here is a code snippet to simulate my real code:

```cs
public static void Main(string[] args)
{
    var fakeData = Enumerable
        .Range(0, 7000)
        .Select(_ => Enumerable.Range(0, 400).ToArray())
        .ToArray();

    const int offset = 100;
    var dataIndices = Enumerable
        .Range(offset, 290)
        .ToArray();

    for (var i = 0; i < 4; i++)
    {
        var s = Stopwatch.StartNew();
        var threads = dataIndices
            .Select(n =>
            {
                var thread = new Thread(() =>
                {
                    foreach (var fake in fakeData)
                    {
                        var sliced = new ArraySegment<int>(fake, n - offset, n - (n - offset));
                        DoThreadWork(sliced);
                    }
                });

                return thread;
            })
            .ToList();

        foreach (var thread in threads)
        {
            thread.Start();
        }
        
        Console.WriteLine($"Before Join: {s.Elapsed.Milliseconds}");

        foreach (var thread in threads)
        {
            thread.Join();
        }
        
        Console.WriteLine($"After Join: {s.Elapsed.Milliseconds}");
    }
}

private static void DoThreadWork(ArraySegment<int> fakeData)
{
    // Commenting out this foreach loop will dramatically increase the speed
    // in which all the threads start
    var a = 0;
    foreach (var fake in fakeData)
    {
        // Simulate thread work
        a += fake;
    }
}
```

Comment: Any reason you don't just use `Parallel.ForEach` or `Enumerable.AsParallel` (optionally with configuration to control the degree of parallelism) instead of reinventing the slicing wheel? At the very least they'll avoid some overhead by using thread pool threads instead of explicitly created ones. And they also won't go off and create 1000 threads if your system doesn't have 1000 cores to process work with -- threads don't magically speed things up. In fact, an overabundance of them will slow things down, as you've likely experienced.

Comment: Are you creating 290 threads??

Comment: @JeroenMostert I was using those at first, but the performance problem still exists. I went to manual thread creation to try and see if something under the hood of `Parallel.ForEach` was causing the issue, and it didn't seem like it was. But no, there is no reason I am not using them.

Comment: @Wyck My computer is pretty powerful, and there are roughly 7000 nodes, and each node has about 400 data sets that need to be computed, so I wanted to try and make it parallel as much as I could. Maybe it's too much, but my CPU is never at max load (only around half usage), and I have a ton of memory to use. Each thread basically does the computation for all the nodes for a specific day. Calculating for one day in isolation takes around 5-10 seconds.

Comment: You might try a simple `Thread.Yield()` at the start to encourage the system to go back to the main thread, rather than using up the slices for the thread just started, but there's no guarantee that'll happen. Trying to spin up more threads at once than there are cores in the system will basically always cause delays, however, simply because your main thread is competing for attention from all the other threads. Not seeing 100% CPU load with a ton of threads is a *bad* sign if the work you're doing is CPU-bound. (If it's also I/O bound, you may benefit from using asynchronous tasks instead.)

Comment: You may have a ton of memory but your system's main memory bus is likely only 64-bits wide.  It takes time to fetch/store memory.  You have 290 threads competing for main memory, likely.  Is this a super-computer?  You probably only have 16 processors or so.  So depending on how much IO they are doing, you probably need only about 16 threads.   Queue the work as _tasks_ and let the system thread pool sort out how many _threads_ are needed.

Comment: @JeroenMostert It shouldn't be I/O bound (unless you mean to memory). All the data is loaded into a dictionary before anything is done. What I have tried that is maybe good enough is to call `Thread.Sleep(10)` at the start of the child threads. The reasoning is because it takes just a couple milliseconds to start them all on the main thread, then all the child threads will wake up and actually do their work once the main thread has started them all.

Comment: Well, you could actually enforce this by giving the child threads less priority, or making their first action to wait on a `ManualResetEventSlim` or somesuch that the main thread flips only when all threads have started. However, while that will kick them off quicker, it just postpones the thundering herd of threads thrashing the system, so it might not improve overall time. Again, though, I think you'll find that if you measure it, 1000 threads do not finish quicker than 500, or 200, or 100; they should take *more* time in total due to bookkeeping overhead (including cache misses).

Comment: With a measly 7000 data points, I actually wouldn't be surprised if a pure sequential processing loop simply beats threaded work entirely, due tot the much friendlier cache access pattern. This depends on your workload, of course, but 1000 threads definitely seems out.

Comment: @MarkLisoway there's no problem with Parallel.ForEach. If the code (which you didn't post) is slow, the problem is in the code. You didn't post what the thread is supposed to do, so it's impossible to help - the most important information is missing. Parallel isn't concurrent isn't asynchronous. If you try to use an in-memory data parallelism construct like `Parallel.ForEach` to accelerate asynchronous code, you'll end up with large delays.

Comment: @MarkLisoway - Starting a thread is an expensive exercise. Each thread consumes a minimum of 1MB of RAM. So if you're creating 1000 threads, you're up to 1GB of  RAM used before you even start processing. You always have to balance the high start up cost of a thread with the work to be done - there must be a significant amount of work done per thread. And the work done quickly diminishes if there aren't any cores to do the work.

Comment: Rereading, it's 7000 nodes with 400 data sets each -- that's a little more work and might benefit from parallel speedup (assuming the work is embarrassingly parallel and requires no synchronization). But still by no more than you have actual cores.

Comment: @MarkLisoway what is the *actual* problem you want to solve? What is the *actual* algorithm you want to use?  Different problems require different parallelization techniques. `Parallel.ForEach` is meant for data parallelism. PLINQ is meant for data parallelism, with the addition of pipelining between operators. The parallelization benefit depends *completely* on the algorithm's behavior - you can't parallelize steps that depend on each other.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos The actual problem is that there is millions of data points that need to be processed, and I was trying to process them as fast as possible. I think I just overestimated the ability multiple threads would have to speed this up, and I will likely go back to `Parallel.ForEach` with a reasonable `MaxDegreeOfParallelism`, and just have to wait it out.

Comment: @MarkLisoway no, that's not the actual problem. That just repeats the first paragraph. All the rest of the question is what you assumed the solution would look like, except you forgot to actually mention the problem. `I want to calculate the performance of 7000 stocks over 1000 days` is an actual problem. `I have to read the stock trades from an HDF5 file` is an actual problem. The algorithm you use to calculate the stock performance is an actual problem. In *none* of these examples would you use raw threads. `Parallel.ForEach` would be suitable in only *parts* of each example, not all

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos I see. I wanted to keep it general in the initial post. But the actual program is a stock back test program I am working on, and I need to compute the back test results for each day (for the past X days), for around 7000 tickers.

Comment: @MarkLisoway when I actually to improve the abysmal performance of an algo trading application to process months of stock trades for algo trading on a manycore machine, the quick&dirty solution was to use workers in a pipeline that would each handle the data for a single stock, read all the data and calculate all the parameters used by the trading algorithms. There was *no* parallelism within a single stock, but that allowed me to use all cores to process one stock each. That alone improved perf 10x. Next step was splitting the IO parts from the CPU parts, using different DOP for each

Comment: @MarkLisoway generalizing parallelism is like generalizing cars - you can't. There are family cars, sports cars, buses, mining trucks. You can't generalize a monster mining truck a Bugatti Veyron and a Smart ForTwo.

Comment: @MarkLisoway `a stock back test program` in that case `Parallel.ForEach` would work reasonably well if there's no coordination between computation steps. There are no dependencies between portfolios so you could parallelize the portfolio tests. That's *not* very efficient though, as all portfolios would need to access the same data, causing blocking while accessing RAM. The solution there can be to *copy* the data so each worker/core gets its own copy

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos Yea I think I just overestimated the benefits of many threads, and just need to suck it up that calculating many possible input permuatations will take a while. I will go back to `Parallel.ForEach` with a DOP of 48. I think I will close this then. Thanks for the help!

Comment: @MarkLisoway on the other hand, many calculations are common across all portfolios. Many calculations only concern a single symbol, which makes them [embarrassingly parallel]9https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Embarrassingly_parallel) calculations. Such problems can be massively parallelized.  You could perform these calculations first (using eg Parallel.Foreach,PLINQ etc) and store the intermediate results. After that, you can perform the steps that require combining those intermediate results

Comment: @MarkLisoway in other cases, simple fixes can provide huge improvements. For example, iterating from the end to find the last 5 items is 1000 times faster than iterating from the start. Sounds trivial, but that's exactly one of the fixes I had to use. In another case, to find the min, max and average price of a symbol, *calculate them while reading the data*. Instead of reading all data then calculating these statistics, you can easily calculate the min, max, count and sum while reading each symbol's values from a file. By the time you read the symbol data, you also have the stats

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos I do read from the end actually, as the actual strategy looks at the current day, and then goes backwards as far as it needs to determine if there is a potential position or not. I will look into pre-calculating anything I can, but I min, max, and average are pre-calculated already.

Comment: @MarkLisoway that's why I say you need to explain the actual problem and the code in the question doesn't help at all. You can use the same technique to find the last item that matches a condition - while processing items in a stream, keep track of the last item encountered that matches the condition along with its index. When you finish processing the stream of trades you'll have the "last" item.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the thread/task pool and limit thread/task count to `2*(CPU Cores)` at most.  Creating more threads doesn't magically make more work get done as you need hardware "threads" to run them (1 per CPU core for non-SMT CPU's, 2 per core for Intel HT, AMD's SMT implementation).  Executing hundreds to thousands of threads that don't have to passively await asynchronous callbacks (i.e. I/O) makes running the threads far less efficient due to thrashing the CPU with context switches for no reason.

Comment: Parallel.X *is* using the thread pool using exactly this as the initial core count. We don't know if the problem is CPU or IO related, or what kind of problem it is. `Parallel.ForEach` is meant for data parallelism when the problem allows easy partitioning